# Как исправить ошибку Function components cannot be given refs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть форма, которую я хочу провалидировать при помощи react hook form. Есть компонент инпута:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../../styles/Input.module.scss'

const Input = (props) => {
    return (
        <input {...props} className={styles.input} />
    );
};

export default Input;
```

И есть сам компонент с формой:

```
const Registration = () => {

    const {
        register, handleSubmit, setError, formState: {
            errors, isValid
        }
    } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        },
        mode: 'onChange'
    })

    const onSubmit = async (values) => {
        console.log(123)
        console.log(values)
    }

    console.log(isValid)

    return (
        <div className={styles.Registration}>
            <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <div className={styles.titles}>
                    <Title>Let's get started</Title>
                    <Subtitle>Registration</Subtitle>
                </div>

                <div className={styles.form__item}>
                    <Input
                        {...register('email', {required: 'Enter email'})}
                        type="email"
                        id="email"
                        placeholder="Email"
                    />
                </div>

                <div className={styles.form__item}>
                    <Input
                        {...register('password', {required: 'Enter password'})}
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                    />
                </div>

                <Button type="submit">Create account</Button>

                <div className={styles.caption}>
                    Already have account? <Link to={'/login'}>Login</Link>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Registration;
```

При использовании компонента с инпутом валидация работать не хочет, всегда переменная isValid равна false. Есть изменить компонент инпута на простой инпут то все работает нормально.
При использовании кастомного инпута, в браузере ошибка:

> Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref
> will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Comment: Не очень понятно, где ошибка возникает. ref в вашем коде отсутствует....

Comment: Swad, да я понимаю, я ref нигде и не использую, гуглил, но решения никакого не нашел, поэтому и пишу сюда.

Comment: К ошибке обычно идет стектрейс, указывающий на файл и номер строки, где ошибка произошла...

Comment: react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `Registration`.
    at Input
    at div
    at form
    at div
    at Registration (http://localhost:5173/src/Pages/Registration.jsx?t=1679519349474:35:7)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=03a897bc:3106:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=03a897bc:3474:5)
    at App

Comment: Swad, прикрепил скрин

Comment: Может стоит попробовать обернуть `Input` в [forwardRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef)?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, уже решил проблему, forwardRef пробовал, не помогло

Comment: И как же решили? Почему не приложили ответ?

Comment: @OliverPatterson Приложил ответ, извиняюсь

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в самом компоненте инпута. Переделал так:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../../styles/Input.module.scss'

const Input = ({register, name, rules, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <input
            {...props}
            {...(register && register(name, rules))}
            className={styles.input}
        />
    );
};

export default Input;
```

Сейчас все работает корректно